# How to make negative numbers not show?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float V1, V0, t;

    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

    cout << "Please enter starting V0, V1, and t in terms of seconds" << endl;
    cin >> V1 >> V0 >> t;
    cout << (V1 - V0) / t << endl;
    cin.get();
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

(Formula is in code) I'm doing a problem and the example shows like this

Enter V0, V1 and t: 5.5 50.9 4.5

The Average is : 10.0889

However from my code which is rounded two decimal places when I enter those numbers I get
The Average is : - 10.09
Am I wrong? Can the average of velocity not be a negative number? And if so how do I make it so the negative does not appear. If anyone could lend me a hand that would be great.

Comment: You have failed to check the result of the input operations.

Comment: You are reading in `V1` before `V0` but you ask the user to input `V0` before `V1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use abs from cmath

```
#include <cmath>
...
cout << abs((V1 - V0) / t) << endl;
```